# How to wrap OpenCV BOW in Python

Tags: python, opencv

I want to wrap additional OpenCV functions such as BoW in Python, how can I do this?

One way maybe to add header files in CMakeLists.txt under modules/python, but how can I only compile OpenCV python module without compiling the whole library?

Answer (score 0):

It's in there in the master branch.

See this: 
http://answers.opencv.org/question/34700/bowkmeanstrainer-in-python/

Download the git repo, and build that. Yes, it's the nightly build, it might have bugs that could break your app, but we gotta take that chance. Apart from all that doubt, the pull request sender did give a sample demo of the code he wrapped for Python.